# insert while loop data from a dynamic table into database with php

Tags: php

What is the easiest way to get data from while loop into dynamic table and insert with php
Any working codes ? Let me learn 
I can successfully get the data in array and echo all the data in a page but I can not insert it into database only last row is inserted

Comment: Hi @Ntungwe. Please, have a look to community guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Post the code you have already ... show what you've done

Comment: <?php include("connect.php"); ?>
 <?php
    $values = array();
 $sname  =  $_POST['sname'];

    $assignment =  $_POST['ass'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `marks` (`sname`) VALUES";
 
    foreach($sname as $value)
  
    {
        $values[] = "($value)";
  
  
    }

 
    $sql .= implode(', ', $values);
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


  
      


?> how do i insert all the post arrays ? again if the array is in letters, it does not insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your array

```
$data = Array(
  Array('col_1' => 1, 'col_2' => 2, 'col_3' => 3),
  Array('col_1' => 4, 'col_2' => 5, 'col_3' => 6),
  Array('col_1' => 7, 'col_2' => 8, 'col_3' => 9),
);
```

then you can insert these 3 rows into your table like this

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
  $query = 'INSERT INTO my_table '.my_insert($row,'id');
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error($query.'<br>'.mysqli_error($connection),E_USER_ERROR);
}

function my_insert($arr,$exclude)
{
  global $connection;

  $vals = Array();
  if(!is_array($exclude)) $exclude = Array($exclude);
  $arr = array_diff_key($arr,array_flip($exclude));
  foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
  {
    if(is_null($value)) $vals[] = 'NULL';
    else
    {
            if($value==='NULL') $vals[] = 'NULL';
            elseif(is_string($value)) $vals[] = '"'.mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $value).'"';
            else $vals[] = $value;
    }
  }
  return '('.implode(',',array_keys($arr)).') VALUES ('.implode(',',$vals).')';
}
```

## UPDATE

Not the best solution - just for a demonstration purpose:

```
$output = '<form method="post" name="items">';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
  $output.= '<div><input type="number" name="a['.$i.']" oninput="compute(this,i,true);"> &nbsp; ';
  $output.= '<input type="number" name="b['.$i.']" oninput="compute(this,i,false);"> &nbsp; ';
  $output.= '<input type="number" name="c['.$i.']" readonly></div>';
}
$output.= '</form>';
$output.= '<script>
function compute(elem, index, first)
{
  var v1 = parseFloat(elem.value), v2;
  if(first)
  {
    v2 = parseFloat(document.items.elements["b[" + index + "]"].value);
  }
  else
  {
    v2 = parseFloat(document.items.elements["a[" + index + "]"].value);
  }
  if(isNaN(v1)) v1 = 0;
  if(isNaN(v2)) v2 = 0;
  document.items.elements["c[" + index + "]"].value = v1 + v2;
}
</script>';
```

Comment: thanks for this, again if i have a table with field from while loop and this table automatically calculated the values in two input fields as the user enters them and then gives the total in the third field, i have a js function that does the calculation and everything works well except when my while loop takes more than one record from the database, my js function does not work again. i guest i nee to call the js function in the loop but i dont know how to do this, any idea ?

Comment: Attach event handlers to each of the fields and in this listener update the result field. The handler function can get the ID of the field on which it is called and thus determine which field should be populated with the result of calculation.

Comment: please any link that i can see an example ?